# Analytically solve equation with two normal CDFs

Tags: probability, optimization, normal-distribution

I'm seeking an analytical solution to the equation
$$ \Phi(x + c) - \Phi(-x) = \alpha $$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function, $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ are known, and $x > 0$ is unknown. I know it's relatively straightforward to solve using a polynomial expansion for $\Phi$, or by using Newton's method or similar, but I'm curious if a simpler solution is possible.

Comment: A scipy function may work like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702216/rearrange-so-as-to-make-w-the-subject-isolate-w-on-just-one-side/4398210#4398210)